# SSRS monthly/daily report

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a variable in my report which holds 2 possible values: 'monthly' and 'daily'. How can I put this variable (lets call it @reportModel). I think it should be somewhere in GROUP BY clause, but don't know how should it look like.

```
DECLARE @reportModel VARCHAR(10)
SET @reportModel = 'monthly'

SELECT P.product, SUM(O.price * O.quantity), O.orderDate
FROM Products AS P
INNER JOIN Orders AS O ON P.ID = O.ID
```

And what now?

Answer (score 0):

How about a stored procedure to handle this, something like.....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rpt_GetData
  @reportModel VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

IF (@reportModel = 'daily')
  BEGIN
   SET @Sql = N' SELECT P.product
                       , SUM(O.price * O.quantity) AS Total
                       , O.orderDate
                FROM Products AS P
                INNER JOIN Orders AS O ON P.ID = O.ID
                GROUP BY P.product , O.orderDate' 
     Exec sp_executesql @Sql
  END
ELSE IF (@reportModel = 'monthly')
  BEGIN
       SET @Sql = N' SELECT P.product
                          , SUM(O.price * O.quantity) AS Total
                          , MONTH(O.orderDate) AS [Month]
                    FROM Products AS P
                    INNER JOIN Orders AS O ON P.ID = O.ID
                    GROUP BY P.product, MONTH(O.orderDate)'
     Exec sp_executesql @Sql            
  END

END
```

Comment: I'd rather throw an exception instead of a `PRINT`. Also worth mentioning that the execution plan for this will potentially horrible.

Comment: Oh, and this is also returning different data formats - `DATETIME` column versus `INT`.

Comment: @DavidG you don't need an except/error here, its only an invalid output , some informational message is enough I think, Also different output/format can be handled in SSRS very easily don't see any reason why we should make it anymore complex at all. Good thing about this proc is all the heavy data processing is being done closer to data source and only required data will be pulled across , and presentation(format) can be handled in reporting application as it should be :)

Comment: Then the `PRINT` is just confusing matters. I know that SSRS can handle the differences, but it's very awkward. The comment about execution plan still stands though.

Comment: @DavidG true, agree about execution plan issue, I have fixed it now anyway :)

Comment: Hmm yes, though I hate dynamic SQL! :) By the way, my preferred solution would be to have 2 reports, or let the report call a different procedure based on the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in the **Group On Expression** of the table or chart rather than doing it in the query.

```
=IIF(Parameters!reportModel.Value = "monthly", Month(Fields!orderDate.Value), Fields!orderDate.Value)
```

If you'd rather do it in the query and don't want to wait for DBAs to get around to deploying a Stored Procedure (not to mention maintaining it whenever there's a change), you could use your parameter in a CASE like:

```
SELECT P.product, SUM(O.price * O.quantity),  
CASE WHEN @reportModel = 'monthly' THEN CAST(MONTH(O.orderDate) AS VARCHAR(12)) 
     ELSE CAST(O.orderDateAS VARCHAR(12)) END AS DT
FROM    WORKFLOW_SHARED.MAIN.VW_CLAIMSOVERPAYMENT
WHERE DATECOMPLETED > '7/1/2015'
GROUP BY P.product, 
CASE WHEN @reportModel = 'monthly' THEN CAST(MONTH(O.orderDate) AS VARCHAR(12)) 
     ELSE CAST(O.orderDateAS VARCHAR(12)) END
```

This way you don't have to maintain two separate reports.

Comment: This would be potentially very slow. Imagine thousands of records per day, this would bring all that data back from the database.

Comment: @DavidG - There's not that much of a difference in time with SQL Server aggregating the data vs Report Server doing it. I have dozens of reports that aggregate thousands (some millions) of records.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there's a huge difference between doing it in the database versus in a client app.

Comment: @HannoverFist I have seen many example where we were having report performance issues and as soon as we moved the the data processing closer to source (SQL Server instead of SSRS), a major improvement was seen immediately. Also why do the extra work anyway? doesnt make any sense mate.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer because I mentioned it in the comments in @M.Ali's answer.

So I would suggest you change thinking slightly with one of these options.

1. Two reports - Simply make a report for daily and another for monthly. Now you have no worries with complex SQL etc.
2. Make 2 stored procedures, one with the `GROUP BY` daily and one monthly. Then in your SSRS dataset, create an expression for you SQL that chooses the procedure based on parameter:

   ```
   =IIf(Parameters!reportModel.Value = "monthly", "GetMonthlyData", "GetDailyData")
   ```

Answer (score -1):

How about something simple like this

```
select 
    P.product
    ,Total = sum(O.price * O.quantity)
    , O.orderDate
from 
    Products as P
    inner join Orders as O on P.ID = O.ID
where
    @reportModel = 'daily'

union all

select 
    P.product
    ,Total = sum(O.price * O.quantity)
    ,[Month] = MONTH(O.orderDate)
from 
    Products as P
    inner JOIN Orders as O on P.ID = O.ID
group by
    P.product
    ,[Month] = MONTH(O.orderDate)
where
    @reportModel = 'monthly'
```